# Excel/VBA - Checking hierarchical ID

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a cell in Excel 2010. I want to check if the value entered there is a hierarchical id or not. How would I do that?

What should be the format of the cell? Should be `general`, `number` or something else?

Lets say my hierarchical ID's are like the following:

```
1.0  
1.0.3  
1.1.1
```

Comment: i tried isnumeric() but its helping only for values like 1.0, 2.0,3.0  not for 1.1.1,1.1.1.1 , etc.. and in my excel sheet the format of that cell is "General"

Comment: 1.1.1 is not numeric anyways ... you can keep the format as General and use the Sort feature.

Comment: @user2063626 thanks for reply ...How can i do that with sort feature... can u explain that with code..?

Comment: www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrymK7jx-34

Comment: Check this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322067

Answer (score 0):

In order for `With ws` to be used you need to used full stops.

For example  `For i = 1 To .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

But I would also change the `.Rows.Count` part as well.  You only need the rows in the used range.